# ¿Por que me lanza la siguiente excepcion "No se puede obtener acceso a un archivo cerrado"? ¿como la controlo? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itextsharp

Estoy modificando un pdf con itextsharp, y luego de modificarlo e intentar abrirlo en un controlador pdfViwer, me lanza la excepcion "No se puede obtener acceso a un archivo cerrado".
El programa lanza la excepcion cuando intento cerrar el pdfStamper.
METODO QUE MODIFICA EL PDF:

```
                    reader.Close();
    
                    if (stamp != null) stamp.Close(); //EN ESTE PUNTO EL PROGRAMA LANZA LA EXCEPCION
    
                    if (fs != null) fs.Close();
    
                    if (document != null) document.Close();
```

Comment: Opino que publicaste mucho código que no es necesario para un problema que ocurre en lás últimas líneas del segundo bloque. Sugiero simplificarlo. Mi recomendación es que leas la documentación de `PdfStamper` para saber si se cierra cuando cierras el `PdfReader`. O prueba cerrar primero el `PdfStamper` y después el `PdfReader`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez, gracias por tu sugerencia, cerrando el pdfStamper primero se soluciono el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba cambiar el orden de las sentencias `Close()`

```
    finally
    {
        if (stamp != null) stamp.Close();

        if (fs != null) fs.Close();

        if (document != null) document.Close();
        //Esta linea al final
        reader.Close();
    }
```

La linea `reader.Close();` parece estar cerrando el objeto `stamp`, ten en cuenta que esta relacionado con el objeto `reader` tenieno en cuenta que lo contruyes en la siguiente linea `stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, fs);` donde reader es el primer argumento de su constructor, comenta si te este cambio resuelve tu problema.

Comment: Lo modifique y resolvio el problema, gracias

Comment: @NachoRodriguez Por nada estamos aqui para ayudar, gracias a ti tambien por marcar como aceptada mi respuesta, me gustaria que si lo crees justo, ademas de me puntearas la respuesta.